# Select subset from IDictionary based on IEnumerable<T> and return IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I need to select a subset of data from an `IDictionary<int,string>` matching keys from an `IEnumerable<T>` and then return a new `IEnumerable<T>`. I am stuck on the syntax and get the error:

> The type arguments for method `Extensions.GetValues<K,
>   V>(IDictionary<K, V>, IEnumerable<K>)` cannot be inferred from the
>   usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

This is my code:

```
public class Subject
{
    public short SubjectID { get; set; }
    public byte CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<V> GetValues<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dict, IEnumerable<K> keys)
    {
        return keys.Select((x) => dict[x]);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<Subject> Translate()
{
   IEnumerable<Subject> selectedSubjects = new Subject[] { new Subject { SubjectID = 1, CategoryID = 2, Title = null } };

   // this is given externally as an IDictionary
   var dict = new Dictionary<int, string> 
   {
          { 1, "Hello" },
          { 2, "Goodbye" }
   };

   // this line produces the error: 
   IEnumerable<Subject> data = dict.GetValues(selectedSubjects);

   // would like to return IEnumerable<Subject> containing SubjectID = 1, CategoryID and Title = "Hello"
   return data;
}
```

I suppose I need to tell it to filter the `dict` using `SubjectID` as `short` somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this will return a list of Subjects matched by the dictionary (where `dict.key == Subject.SubjectID`), updating `Subject.Title = dict.value`:

```
return dict.Keys.Join(
    selectedSubjects, 
    k => k, 
    s => (Int32)s.SubjectID, 
    (k, s) => new Subject
    {
        SubjectID = s.SubjectID, 
        CategoryID = s.CategoryID, 
        Title = dict[k] 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. At least that solved the problem with the types, but it is not giving the correct data. I actually need the int and string values from the Dictionary. In SQL-pseudo it would be something like 

`SELECT [ColumnINT], [ColumnSTRING] FROM Dictionary WHERE DictionaryID IN (selectedSubjects)`

- and then return these values to the `IEnumerable<Subject>`

Comment: Your latest edit does not return IEnumerable<Subject> but instead IEnumerable<string>

Comment: Sorry, you are right, it returns the Values from the dictionary matching the SubjectID's. Would you like the matching Subjects returned or do you want to update the Subject with the value from the matching dictionary key and then return those modified Subjects?

Comment: I have updated the question. But yes, basically it could just do a copy of the Title to the Subjects - maybe we could rid the filtering altogether.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer, this returns a Subject with a Title of 'Hello'. If this is correct, please mark my answer. Thanks. Sorry for the initial confusion.

Comment: Works perfect :) As a small optimization, the cast `(Int32)` can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple `yield` IEnumerable.  EG

```
public static IEnumerable<V> GetValues<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dict, IEnumerable<K> keys)
{
    foreach (var key in keys)
    {
        if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out V value))
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }            
}
```

Then something like:

```
var selectedSubjectIds = selectedSubjects.Select(s => s.SubjectID);
IEnumerable<Subject> data = dict.GetValues(selectedSubjectIds);
```

Comment: Same error but thanks for the effort though. I accepted the answer from Carlo Bos.